# Best practice for transferring images between microservices

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, image-processing

I am trying to pass an image from one `microservice` to another `microservice` as a parameter where the image would be processed.
What is the best way to send this image across the services, image is in `jpg` format  .

What I have tried is :

```
import binascii

f1 = open("imageName.jpg","rb")    
sendToServiceTwo(binascii.hexlify(f1.read()))
```

The size of the image is around `28kb` but in the converted hexadecimal format the size is increased to `48kb` . I don't want to apply any compression while transferring the data.

Comment: It depends on what your communication pipe is plus many other factors. Why not just pass binary? For a 28kb file, it makes very little difference whether the transfer payload is a bit bigger.

Comment: @tdelaney the image size what I have written was just an example , The image sizes could be in Mega Bytes as well.

Comment: @kkk I have the exact same issue. Do you have any solution for me?